# "register_activation_hook" function does not work in wordpress (AppServer)

Tags: wordpress

Appserv (localhost) is installed on my own computer. I'm trying to create a mysql table. But unfortunately the `register_activation_hook` function does not work.

I am trying to create a table with the `create_table` function below.

```
<?php
    function create_table()
     {
        global $wpdb;
        $charset = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
        $tablo_adi = $wpdb->prefix."bilgiler";

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $tablo_adi(
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
        mail VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
        phone VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE KEY id (id)) $charset;";

        require_once(ABSPATH. "wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php"); 

        dbDelta($sql);
        
    } register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'create_table'); ?>
```

The page with the code:

```
<?php 
/*
Plugin name: 2.Ders
plugin URI: https://www.google.com
Description: 2.Derste 
Version: 0.2 (Beta)
Author: Baran Kanat
Author URI: https://www.gogole.com/developer/
*/

add_action("admin_menu","ders_iki");

function ders_iki()
{
    add_menu_page("Ders iki - Title","ders-iki-menu","manage_options","ders-iki","eklenti_icerigi","dashicons-wordpress-alt");

}

function eklenti_icerigi() 
 {?>
    <form method="POST">
        <br>
        <label>İsim:</label>
        <input type="text" name="isim"><br><br>
        <label>E-posta</label>
        <input type="email" name="eposta"><br><br>
        <label>Telefon</label>
        <input type="number" name="telefon">
        <input type="submit" name="gonder">
    </form>




    <?php
    function create_table()
     {
        global $wpdb;
        $charset = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
        $tablo_adi = $wpdb->prefix."bilgiler";

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $tablo_adi(
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        isim VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
        eposta VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
        telefon VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE KEY id (id)) $charset;";

        require_once(ABSPATH. "wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php"); 

        dbDelta($sql);

 
        
    } register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'create_table');
        

        if (isset($_POST['gonder'])) 
        {
            global $wpdb;
            $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix."bilgiler",
            array(
            "isim" => $_POST['isim'],
            "eposta" => $_POST['eposta'],
            "telefon" => $_POST['telefon']
        ));}
        

     } 
    
 

 ?>
```

Can you help with this problem?

Server information: php version 7.2, Appserv (Localhost)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its all working for me. I am able to activate plugin and add data to the table as well on submit.

Try this paste it as exactly and see if this works.

```
 /*
    Plugin name: 2.Ders
    plugin URI: https://www.google.com
    Description: 2.Derste 
    Version: 0.2 (Beta)
    Author: Baran Kanat
    Author URI: https://www.gogole.com/developer/
    */

add_action("admin_menu","ders_iki");

function ders_iki()
{
    add_menu_page("Ders iki - Title","ders-iki-menu","manage_options","ders-iki","eklenti_icerigi","dashicons-wordpress-alt");

}

function eklenti_icerigi() 
 {?>
<form method="POST">
    <br>
    <label>İsim:</label>
    <input type="text" name="isim"><br><br>
    <label>E-posta</label>
    <input type="email" name="eposta"><br><br>
    <label>Telefon</label>
    <input type="number" name="telefon">
    <input type="submit" name="gonder">
</form>

<?php
    function create_table() {
        global $wpdb;

        $tablo_adi = 'testing_hook';

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $tablo_adi(
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
        mail VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
        phone VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE KEY id (id)) $charset;";

        require_once(ABSPATH. "wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php"); 
        dbDelta($sql);
    } 


  register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'create_table'); 


        if (isset($_POST['gonder'])) 
        {
            global $wpdb;
            $wpdb->insert("testing_hook",
            array(
            "name" => $_POST['isim'],
            "mail" => $_POST['eposta'],
            "phone" => $_POST['telefon']
        ));

        }
     }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. I solved the problem,   I think the main source of the problem is that it is in the same place as the table creation page and the page content function.

Comment: Glad that its all working for your. I think if should not matter where your code is table creation code us. Its on server side and your form on the client side. As soon as the you activate plugin the hook runs on the server side and creates the sql table. You fill the form and data gets inserted to that table we create on activation hook , Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try this.